# In apache Kafka, who would populate the RecordMetadata and where does this information reside once the producer got it?

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm running a test to understand how the producer would react if the all the brokers in the kafka cluster are down. During this testing, I observed that I'm getting below error where as 45000 ms is the value for 'max.block.ms'.

> Failed to send; nested exception is
>   org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Topic test.topic not
>   present in metadata after 45000 ms

I believe this metadata is nothing but **RecordMetadata**. Now my question is, who would populate the **RecordMetadata** and where does this information reside once the producer got it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no records, so it's actually topic metadata.

As answered on your previous question, you'll get these logs if you cannot connect to the bootstrap addresses.

Zookeeper holds topic metadata